# Simplified enquiry re: orderable connected lists

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can localStorage / session storage / cookie storage functionality be added to connected lists, perhaps by way of a JSON stringify?

It seems relatively easy to use browser storage for list order data on a single list, but nowhere can I find an example of how to store order information locally when using connected lists.

```
<!-- Javascript -->
    <script>
    $(function () {
        $("#items1,#items2,#items3").sortable({
            connectWith: "#items1,#items2,#items3",
            start: function (event, ui) {
                ui.item.toggleClass("highlight");
            },
            stop: function (event, ui) {
                ui.item.toggleClass("highlight");
            }
        });
        $("#items1,#items2,#items3").disableSelection();
    });
    </script>

    <!-- HTML -->
    <ul id="items1" class="items">
        <li class="list">Item 1-1</li>
        <li class="list">Item 1-2</li>
        <li class="list">Item 1-3</li>
        <li class="list">Item 1-4</li>
        <li class="list">Item 1-5</li>
        <li class="list">Item 1-6</li>    
    </ul>
    <ul id="items2" class="items">
        <li class="list g">Item 2-1</li>
        <li class="list g">Item 2-2</li>
        <li class="list g">Item 2-3</li>
        <li class="list g">Item 2-4</li>
        <li class="list g">Item 2-5</li>
        <li class="list g">Item 2-6</li>    
    </ul>
    <ul id="items3" class="items">
        <li class="list o">Item 3-1</li>
        <li class="list o">Item 3-2</li>
        <li class="list o">Item 3-3</li>
        <li class="list o">Item 3-4</li>
        <li class="list o">Item 3-5</li>
        <li class="list o">Item 3-6</li>    
    </ul>
```

Comment: What if anything, does this have to do with mySQL?

Comment: Ah. Sorry. If I can get this to work with local storage, it is intended that the list contents will be pulled from a database.